# Is it safe to remove the object files if I keep the binary?

Tags: compilation, gnu-make, binaryfiles, scons

After compiling a (C/C++) code with GNU Make (or SCons) and successfully creating a binary, is there any reason to keep the `.o` object files?

Can I always safely remove them or are there cases where they are referenced by the binary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have created your executable by linking the object files (and
the libraries on which they depend) the object files are waste material *as far
your executable is concerned*. You can safely delete them.

However, if you build your executable with a build system such as GNU Make
or Scons it is certainly inadvisable to make that build system delete the
object files of a successful build.

The main purpose of such a build system is to rebuild your executable,
when it needs rebuilt, with the smallest amount of rebuilding that is
necessary. If the executable `prog` requires object files `a.o`, `b.o` and `c.o` to
be linked and you change only the source file `c.c`, then the build system
will know that it can rebuild `prog` merely by recompiling `c.c`
and then relinking `prog` with the new `c.o` plus the old `a.o` and `b.o`.

But it can only deliver this economy if the old `a.o` and `b.o` still exist.
If you've deleted them with your last successful build then `prog` must
be rebuilt from scratch, although the new `a.o` and `b.o` will be the same
as the old ones: a waste of time.

There will of course be occasions when you *want* to rebuild from scratch, and
to do so you must first delete all the object files. To support that
need in GNU Make you provide your project with a [phony target](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html),
conventionally called `clean`, that does nothing but delete the object files
and any other intermediate by-products of the build. You invoke it explictly with:

```
make clean
```

In Scons, you don't need to write anything extra in your build project to
clean out intermediate prodpucts. You just run `scons -c` or `scons --clean`.
But in either case, you do not want to delete the object files of a successful
build *by default*, as that defeats the purpose of the build system.

Comment: So the only reason to keep them is to save compilation time in case a re-build is needed in the future, right? In my scenario, I want to free disk space by deleting the object files of big packages that I have compiled/installed from source, so it makes sense if I can save a few GB ;-) .

Comment: By the way, I observed that scons -c (and I guess also make clean) also deletes the actual binary.

Comment: With gnu make, "make clean" will just run the "clean:" rule in your makefile, so it can do whatever you want. You can have both "clean", "cleanobjs", and "cleandist" rules that each do different things, one deleting the binary and the other not, for instance. The disadvantage is that with an improperly coded 'clean' rule, you may leave things behind that you wanted to delete and it can be hard to notice.